# Is my while loop incorrectly comparing two lists?

Tags: python, list, random

My program randomly selects four items from the list, sorts them, and compares them to the list called 'my_ticket', which is also sorted.

My program is supposed to repeat selecting the four items until the four items it selects match the list 'my_ticket'.

Currently, the loop runs and never finds a match, if someone can point out the error(s) in my program I would appreciate it.

My program:

```
from random import choice
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

# check if picks and my_ticket match
def check_if_equal(list_one, list_two):

    return sorted(str(list_one)) == sorted(str(list_two))

my_ticket = [1, 3, 'a', 'c']
picks = []
counter = 0

while check_if_equal(my_ticket, picks) == False:

    for pick in range(4):
        pick = choice(list)
        picks.append(pick)
        counter += 1
    print(picks)
```

Comment: `sorted(str(list_one)) == sorted(str(list_two))` is not correct.  With this logic, the following three lists are all considered equal: `['a', 'b', 'c']`, `['ab', '', 'c']`, `['cab', '', '']`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by this?  If you know you want a specific arrangement, why waste time trying to match it randomly?  And by calling `choice` one at a time, you are going to get duplicates.  You want `picks = choice(list,4)`, but even then there 1,365 unique combinations.

Comment: I'm trying to see how many tries it takes to come up with a winning ticket from random selections.

Comment: There is an easy analytical answer.  There are 1,365 unique combinations (15C4).  Thus, on average, it will take 1365/2 or 682 loops to get a match.

Comment: Thank you. This is an exercise in the Python Crash Course book, that's why I'm trying to run the loop until it picks a match.

Comment: @TimRoberts These are combinations with replacement, which are 3060 (`18C4`).

Comment: @schwobaseggl  There are only 15 elements, not 18, and although his code allowed replacements, he didn't want that.

Comment: @TimRoberts That he didn't want them wasn't what the code indicated. Anyway, the formula for comb. of r elements with repetitions from a pool of n is `(n+r-1) over r`, that is in this case `(15+4-1) over 4 = 18 over 4` or `18C4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to clear `picks` for every loop iteration:

```
while not check_if_equal(my_ticket, picks):
    picks = random.choice(lst, 4)  # do not ues the varaible name `list`
```

Also, don't turn your lists into strings, just compare sorted lists (better use a key function to handle objects of different types):

```
def check_if_equal(list_one, list_two):
    return sorted(list_one, key=str) == sorted(list_two, key=str)
```

Note that sorting is log-linear, so (at least algorithmically) order-insensitive comparison is better done using a `collections.Counter` (whose count collection has linear complexity):

```
from collections import Counter

def check_if_equal(list_one, list_two):
    return Counter(list_one) == Counter(list_two)
```

Comment: You can't remove the `str()` because then `sorted()` won't work comparing ints and strings.

Comment: Good point, still, using a key function is still more elegant, and the `Counter` method does not have that issue with heterogenous data.

Comment: Again, the `for` loop is dumb.  The `while` loop should just be `picks = choice(list,4)` / `print(picks)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset your list before every iteration of the while loop:

```
from random import choice
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

# check if picks and my_ticket match
def check_if_equal(list_one, list_two):

    return sorted(str(list_one)) == sorted(str(list_two))

my_ticket = [1, 3, 'a', 'c']
picks = []
counter = 0

while check_if_equal(my_ticket, picks) == False:
    picks = []
    for pick in range(4):
        pick = choice(list)
        picks.append(pick)
        counter += 1
    print(picks)
```

Also, if you want an exact match of elements in the same order, try changing your check_if_equal function:

```
def check_if_equal(list_one, list_two):
    if len(list_two) == 0:
      return False
    for i in range(len(list_one)):
      if list_one[i] != list_two[i]:
        return False
    return True
```

The probability of it matching is very low so you can check to make sure your code works with this shortened test case:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I calculated the probability of the original test getting it per try and it's (1/15)^4 = 1/50625, and my code got it on like the 60 thousandth try lmaoo

Comment: The whole `for` loop concept is stupid.  The entire `while` loop can be replaced by `picks = choice(list,4)` / `print(picks)`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'm still learning, so I will apply that.

Comment: No problem! Python is a great language to get started in so it's good that you are exploring these concepts with Python, as in my opinion and experience, learning these fundamentals in Python makes it so much easier to apply in other languages

Comment: Accepted your answer, sorry for not doing it sooner, thank you!

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't accept my answer, you accepted someone elses.